# Couldn't load gnustl_shared: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio

I'm trying to add some native code to my android project. 
But got problem with `gnustl_shared` library:

> E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't
>   load gnustl_shared: findLibrary returned null

I have `libgnustl_shared.so` in libs directory, so I have no idea how to solve the problem. I'm using android studio. Can it be ide's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Load library from **libs** folder by following code :

```
static
{
     System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
}
```

**Put above code in .java file where native function declaration is given**